# Python naming convention for functions returning functions

Tags: python, coding-style, naming-conventions

What is the Python naming convention, if any, for functions that return another function?

Comment: There isn't one. Just name your function sensibly.

Comment: I'm surprised this question is closed. To me, it is a precise and clear question, which is amenable to clear, useful, non-controversial answers. Both of the answers below I find useful: (kzh) there is no convention, and (GShearer) an idea for a convention, taken from Cocoa. Glad that the question was not closed before these answers existed!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Function decorators](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0318/#examples) are examples of functions that return functions.  In the (linked) example section, there does not seem to be any standard naming convention used.  I don't think that there is a convention.  If you think there should be, you can always [introduce a PEP](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0001/#submitting-a-pep). Although, there probably should not be a standard.  Just [name the function sensibly](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#naming-conventions).

Comment: I'm think introducing a PEP for a naming convention for this specific use case is quite frankly, daft. Even PEP8 isn't adhered to - just name it sensibly.

Comment: It's not that specific of a use case though.  Like I said in my answer, this applies to ALL methods that return something.  Just use the type as the first word in the method, whether its a string/number/method whatever.  Then you always know what you are getting out of a method without needing to read docstrings or code

Comment: I agree. I don't think that there should be a PEP for it, but I was pointing the OP to where these things get standardized.

Answer (score 1):

Like @Martijn Pieters said, there isn't one, and like @kzh said, you could introduce a PEP.  When there is something I run into in python that does not fit PEP-8, I look to Cocoa (Apple's frameworks).

According to Cocoa, a method should tell me exactly what it does by its name, and if it returns something, that something should be the first word in the selector (method name).

For Example,

a method that returns a string based on some other param should read:

```
def stringForObjectNamed(anObjectName):
```

or

```
def string_for_object_named(an_object_name):
```

So in your case:

```
def function_for_param1_and_param2(param1, param2):
```

or

```
def method_for_param1_and_param2(param1, param2):
```

Giving me the type in the beginning, so i don't need to inspect the method to figure out what it should give me.  And since python is not statically typed, this is incredibly helpful.

Comment: I disagree with putting the type in the function name. I can always inspect that. Tell me what the object represents instead (eg `def description_for_object_named(an_object_name):`). Putting the argument names in the function is also redundant when python has name arguments (`description_for(object_name=an_object_name)`).

Comment: This suggestion amounts to a form of [Hungarian notation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hungarian_notation). You're welcome to use it, but it's not idiomatic Python at all. Part of the point of dynamic typing is that you can return various types using the same function. Also, just as a matter of style, Python programmers tend to prefer names that are not nearly as verbose as your examples.

Comment: UNLESS you know what type you are returning.  If you are returning a 'staticy' type, then why would you want to inspect the code.  I'm not saying I'm right and your wrong.  I'm just saying that when I'm operating in a large project with 35 source files, I dont always want to go looking for a method definition

Comment: I'm referring to when I'm in ViM, using auto completions.  Your argument for named parameters does me no good there.  If I try to auto-complete (description_for()), and it happens to take 3 params, now i need to go inspect docs to figure out what they are, thats redundant

Comment: and I would still argue that string_description_for() would be more valid, description is ambiguous, it could be a dict or any number of types.  If it IS going to be dynamic, and return all kinds of types, then fine, leave it out.  If it IS going to be specific and return a dict or a string, then I'd rather know by the method name what it returns.  I may just be corrupted by Cocoa, but its ohhh so good, and I like self-documented code :)

Comment: my point is I would rather take 2 extra seconds typing 2-3 extra words in a method name, than spending 2 extra minutes searching through documentation, I'll end up with a finished product faster in a large project.  And i'll actually be able to jump back into it 9 months from now when I'm a different person and can't remember why i wrote the code in the first place. WITHOUT needing to lookup documentation

Comment: @G hopefully you don't need to come back here in nine months and read all these comments :)

Comment: Lol truth.  My point was that "name stuff sensibly" is a terrible answer.  DEFINE sensibly.  I was attempting to give a practical answer.  Not some psuedo-religious answer about being pythonic.  Whats more important? Being pythonic or writing easy to manage code.  This is the real world not academics.

Comment: @G.Shearer: Embedding types in names becomes popular when a language + IDE fail to make that unnecessary. In the long run, Python 3 type annotations will be a preferable way to solve this; then IDE can immediately provide type information, and names can be kept simple. Until then, I find myself agreeing with you, though I despise the clutter.

Comment: Actually, considering my own style, I wouldn't necessarily put a type as the first word. Rather, I choose the most descriptive word possible (and such word is often associated with a type). For example, I would `def name..()`. I would NOT `def string_name..()`. Because a name is generally a string. There is a tradeoff between name length and descriptiveness. My preference falls somewhere in the middle of that tradeoff. I think "Put the most essential pieces of info in the name, but try not to be overly long."